# How to get certificate list from Microsoft CA?

Tags: active-directory, wmi, windows-server-2012

I have a windows server 2012 and I want to get all certificates from this server with remote connection. Is there any way to get certificates remotely? After some research I think I can get this certificates with WMI but I don't know how. Even certificate names are enough for me but I can't find a way to get this names from powershell.

Comment: http://blog.backslasher.net/remotley-viewing-machine-certificates-with-minimal-permissions.html

Answer (score -1):

Is there an option to use PowerShell instead of WMI?
If yes, check the following article https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scotts-it-blog/2014/12/30/working-with-certificates-in-powershell/

Comment: You might want to slightly expand your answer for +50 rep.

Comment: This is for the certificate store and doesn't appear to linked to the CA store.

Comment: @DustWolf First of all thank you for the negative vote resurrecting of this question from 2016. Second - have a look on the section "Importing and Exporting Certificates" in the article linked in my answer above. If you have a specific question that is not covered by this, feel free to post a new question.